Monitor sporadically goes black (Intel HD Graphics 530)
I use an HP EliteDesk 800 G2 (onboard Intel HD Graphics 530) with Ubuntu (currently 22.04.5 LTS w/ Linux 6.8.0-47-generic) for several years without problems.  Recently my display turns black sporadically.  It is entirely unpredictable.  Sometimes it will not happen all day, then happen ten times in an hour.  It will come back by itself within 2-15 seconds.
My typical monitor is connected via a DisplayPort cable.  I added a monitor with VGA which also has the problem, but not at the same time as the DisplayPort monitor.  So I think I've eliminated the monitor and cables as a source of the problem.
These users https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Operating-Systems-and-Recovery/Intel-HD-530-Graphics-driver-issue/td-p/7297165 had the same issue on Windows in 2019 and one found that rolling back their driver solved the problem.  I don't know how to do that on Ubuntu.
output of sudo lshw -c video:
  *-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: HD Graphics 530
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   logical name: /dev/fb0
   version: 06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
   configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=3440,1440
   resources: irq:145 memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

Graphics output of inxi -Fxz:
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 530 vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: i915
    v: kernel bus-ID: 00:02.0
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915 resolution: 3440x1440~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 530 (SKL GT2)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 direct render: Yes

Any advice would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Diagnosis: latest kernel breaks extended idle power state.
Solution: enter the bios and disable it.
Source: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=430415
